# Map over object and push key to value in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following object of objects:

```
expenditures: {
    byId: {
      '-LK6x1d5vJxhsbtD4KvF': {
        categoryId: 12,
        createdAt: 1534510508671,
        day: 1534464000000,
        description: 'stuff',
        updatedAt: 1534510508671,
        value: -1.2
      },
      '-LK6x5tCFOrQZ0nXZO2x': {
        categoryId: 13,
        createdAt: 1534510526087,
        day: 1534464000000,
        description: 'food',
        updatedAt: 1534510526087,
        value: -8.6
      },
   }
}
```

What I want to do is to map over the `byId` object and for each element put their key as an `id` value. Something like this:

```
expenditures: {
    byId: {
      '-LK6x1d5vJxhsbtD4KvF': {
        categoryId: 12,
        createdAt: 1534510508671,
        day: 1534464000000,
        description: 'stuff',
        updatedAt: 1534510508671,
        value: -1.2,
        id: '-LK6x1d5vJxhsbtD4KvF',
      },
      '-LK6x5tCFOrQZ0nXZO2x': {
        categoryId: 13,
        createdAt: 1534510526087,
        day: 1534464000000,
        description: 'food',
        updatedAt: 1534510526087,
        value: -8.6,
        id: '-LK6x5tCFOrQZ0nXZO2x',
      },
   }
}
```

How can I achieve that? I know who to map over the object using `Object.keys()` or `Object.values()` but I don't know how to put the keys as values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can achieve your goal with ES6 object spread operator.

```
const expendituresWithId = {
    byId: Object.keys(expenditures.byId).map(key => {
        return {
            [key]: {
                ...expenditures.byId[key],
                id: key
            }
        }
    })
}
```

With this solution, you do not change the original object.

Answer (score 2):

Store the key per iteration as another property; you can use `for..in`, e.g.:

```js
const expenditures = {
    byId: {
      '-LK6x1d5vJxhsbtD4KvF': {
        categoryId: 12,
        createdAt: 1534510508671,
        day: 1534464000000,
        description: 'stuff',
        updatedAt: 1534510508671,
        value: -1.2
      },
      '-LK6x5tCFOrQZ0nXZO2x': {
        categoryId: 13,
        createdAt: 1534510526087,
        day: 1534464000000,
        description: 'food',
        updatedAt: 1534510526087,
        value: -8.6
      },
   }
}

for (const key in expenditures.byId) {
    expenditures.byId[key].id = key
}

console.log(expenditures.byId);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one solution:

```
Object.keys(expenditures.byId).forEach(id => expenditures.byId[id].id = id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach you can use that takes advantage of some ES6 features:

```js
const expenditures = {
  byId: {
    '-LK6x1d5vJxhsbtD4KvF': {
      categoryId: 12,
      createdAt: 1534510508671,
      day: 1534464000000,
      description: 'stuff',
      updatedAt: 1534510508671,
      value: -1.2
    },
    '-LK6x5tCFOrQZ0nXZO2x': {
      categoryId: 13,
      createdAt: 1534510526087,
      day: 1534464000000,
      description: 'food',
      updatedAt: 1534510526087,
      value: -8.6
    },
  }
};

const updatedExpenditures = Object.entries(expenditures.byId).reduce((accum, kvPair, arr) => {
  let [key, value] = kvPair;
  accum[key] = Object.assign({
    id: key
  }, value);
  return accum;
}, {});

console.log(updatedExpenditures);
```